# Create Order to Spree ecommerce using iOS app

Tags: spree

In my app, i want to order a product in spree e-commerce by iPhone app. I easily get the products name and their detail but while creating order for products it's return the error in html page :

```
 <h1>
   TypeError
   in Spree::Api::V1::OrdersController#create
 </h1>
   <pre>can't convert Symbol into Integer</pre>
```

I m sending post request as:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:3000/api/orders"];
NSURL *urlForBuy = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urlForBuy];
NSString *idVariant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"order[line_items][%d][variant_id]",0];
NSString *qnty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"order[line_items][%d][quantity]",0];
NSString *idVariantValue = @"123456";
[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[idVariantValue intValue]] forKey:idVariant];
[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1] forKey:qnty];
[request setPostValue:@"<my admin token>" forKey:@"token"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(buyResponse:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(buyResponse_failed:)];
[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];
```

Also, this url i get from REST api documentation of Spree which is: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/rest.html

Another thing I want to know what is [line_items] in this url... Also if their is any tutorial apart from above url?...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Orders are created through the API by passing in line items as shown in [this test](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/api/spec/controllers/spree/api/v1/orders_controller_spec.rb#L54-63).

```
api_post :create, :order => { 
  :line_items => [
    { 
      :variant_id => variant.to_param,
      :quantity => 5 
    }
  ]
}
```

The `line_items` parameter is expected to be an array of hashes, consisting of a `variant_id` and a `quantity` field. The [documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/rest.html) says the request looks like this:

```
POST /api/orders?order[line_items][0][variant_id]=1&order[line_items[0][quantity]=5
```

I hope that helps you understand it better!

Comment: Thanks for ur response...can you please take a look at my parameters as i think they are not correct..here i m sending two parameters...i.e.key => value ("order[line_items][0][variant_id] => 12345"  and  "order[line_items][0][quantity] => 1")...they are coorect or not?

Comment: waiting for reponse .pls help

Comment: You posted "waiting for response" *one hour* after your first comment. It's a bit rude to expect another response immediately. I am not your personal manslave.

Comment: In answer to your question: I don't know how the server is receiving those parameters, so I don't know if it's correct or not. Show me the Rails logs for the request and I can tell you.